# How to make simple dicitonary J2ME

Tags: dictionary, find, java-me, text-files

I am beginner in JavaME. I'd like to make simple dicitionary. The source data is placed on "data.txt" file in "res" directory. The structure is like this:

#apple=kind of fruit; 
 #spinach=kind of vegetable;

The flow is so simple. User enters word that he want to search in a text field, e.g "apple", system take the user input, read the "data.txt", search the matched word in it, take corresponding word, and display it to another textfield/textbox.

I've managed to read whole "data.txt" using this code..

```
private String readDataText() {
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("data.txt");
    try {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        int chr, i=0;
        while ((chr = is.read()) != -1)
            sb.append((char) chr);
        return sb.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

but I still dont know how to split it, find the matched word with the user input and take corresponding word. Hope somebody willing to share his/her knowledge to help me..

Answer (score -1):

Basically you want something like this:

```
private String readDataText() {
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("data.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] split = line.split("=");
            if (split[0].equals("#someFruit"))
                return split[1];
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
    return null;
}
```

1. Read the line using a `BufferedReader`, no need to handle single `char`s.
2. Split the line by the `=` token
3. Check if the key in the dictionary is the wanted key, if so, return the value.

Comment: If the value contains "=", the result will only contain the first part

Comment: We cant use BufferedReader in J2ME, can we?

Comment: sorry, but still unclear for me. Would u mind to give direct explanation..?

Comment: Read the answers - they are more than helpful.